# virtual inheritance and signature overlapping

Tags: c++

Let's say we have following code:

```
struct A{
    virtual ~A(){}

    void f(){
        p = 42;
    }

    int p;
};

struct B : public virtual A{};
struct C : public virtual A{};
struct D : public B, public C, public A{}; //let's add non-virtual inheritance

int main(){
    D* pA = new D();
    pA->A::f(); //!

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to set p to 42 in the most base class A?
Following construction pA->A::f(); sets p to 42 for non-virtual inherited class A. Can we do that without cast?

Comment: what's the question exactly ? inheriting virtually means you get one instance of A...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, there is no cast: you just qualify which version of `A` you want as there are more than one. Of course, the notation you have chosen actually doesn't work because it doesn't resolve the ambiguity in the first place. I guess you meant to use something like

```
pA->B::f();
```

If you don't want to put the burden of choosing which member function to call on the user of your class, you'll have to provide suitable forwarding functions for `D` e.g.:

```
void D::f() { this->B::f(); }
```

Comment: I've just realized that I can call pA->B::A::f(); :) and this will change value of the most base class A.

Comment: You can omit the `A::` part: once you have chosen the start of a path which unambiguously leads to the function you don't need further qualification. Well, unless the function is virtual and you want to make sure you call the base version.